# Securing Mosquitto Connections - MQTT

Tags: raspberry-pi, mqtt, mosquitto

I set up a broker on a windows pc which is publishing messages to raspberry pis (clients). On the same windows machine I'm running a node.js Server which is also a mosquitto client which can publish messages to the broker running on the same windows machine.

I looked up (by simple googling and reading the official documentation) how I can secure the `moquitto`connections. But I still ran into some issues:

- How can I only allow a mosquitto broker to communicate with clients
  running on the same machine? (e.g. for simply publishing sensor
  values to a local frontend via websockets - which I'm already doing)
- Do local (on the same machine) clients require the username and
  password if specified?
- Why won't this configuration not require an username and a password
  when the client is connecting to the broker?

My `mosquitto.conf`:

```
allow_anonymous false
password_file C:\Program Files (x86)\mosquitto
```

Password file is at the specified location and valid.

`mosquitto -c mosquitto.conf` is not throwing any error.

- Can I still use the username and password when including encryption
  `mosquitto-tls`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Listeners can be bound to a specific interface e.g. 127.0.0.1 which will only allow connections from the localhost.

```
listener 1885 127.0.0.1
```

If you want to restrict the whole broker to only listen for local connections use the `bind_adddress` config option to change the default listener to only listen on 127.0.0.1 rather than 0.0.0.0 (this address represents ALL network interfaces on the machine)

If password based authentication is configured it applies to ALL listeners so if you set up a localhost only listener you will still need to supply a username and password.

You can use TLS and username and password based authentication unless you use client side certificates and enable the `use_identity_as_username` and `require_certificate`

Comment: Just for completion: The `mosquitto` broker only reads the `mosquitto.conf` on windows if you run it as a service

Comment: Wrong, it will always read it if passed on the command line with the `-c` option

Comment: from the `readme-windows.txt` 

When running as a service, the configuration in mosquitto.conf in the
installation directory is used so modify this to your needs.